# Encoding class's GetChars method

Tags: c#

```
public  int GetChars (byte[] bytes, int byteIndex, int byteCount,
                                 char[] chars, int charIndex);
```

I would like to know the implementation of this method. But I couldn't find the source code for this ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getchars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Click on each method (it's overloaded) and there is code samples

Comment: @prospector that is how to use it, not how it is implemented

Comment: Much of the .NET Framework's code has been opened for anyone to review: search for it.  Alternatively check out DotPeek, JustDecompile, or a similar tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can get most of the Framework source code online now:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/encoding.cs,3b6090c501893c25

Comment: Thanks, but MS doesn't publish its implmentation.

Comment: I need to view the implementation of the method I post. I read all encoding.cs